# Node.js and rendering views and templates stored in database

Tags: node.js, ejs, templating, dust.js

Im am currently trying out different node.js templating engines, including dust.js

Is it feasible to store all layout and view content in a database instead of the file system?   Is there any templating engine which would be a better fit for this  case?

Ideally i would create an administration screen where i could edit all master layouts and views, without requiring any file copying.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely feasible, you'll just be responsible for your own template compilation / hydration.  Assuming you're using Express, the built-in view engine expects templates to be on the file system, so if you're not going to have them there you have three choices:

1) fork express to remove that check
2) pre-cache all your views in the view cache when the app starts up (so that it pulls them from the cache rather than looking at the file system)
3) ignore the view rendering Express provides and just compile your templates yourself.

Doing 3 seems like the most natural choice, but realize there's a reason Express caches compiled templates, so you may consider building your own template cache (and dealing with cache invalidation when stuff gets updated).

Actually, a 4th method which may or may not work better (untested) would be to use Express's default views rendering, but on app startup write all your view files to a virtual drive using them `temp` module ([here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/temp))